# Extrude Face Along Normals - Uneven & Bended

Tags: extrude

I started a new file on Blender and when I try to extrude my faces along normal, they come off as "bent". This has never happened to me before.

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: did you check Even Offset after extruding?

Comment: Agree with MikoCG - in the _Operator Panel_ (that little box that pops up in the bottom left after performing an action), there is an option called "Offfset Even" which must be checked after the extrude operation (but before doing anything else, such as clicking away from the object, or the panel will disappear).

Comment: Thanks heaps guys, that was indeed the solution!